# Combining array of objects according to field in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to build an aggregation that will return the documents with the biggest number of objects in one of the fields, after combining the field.

Let's say that have this following documents that two of them contains the same id inside the `movie` field

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b79bb0c15d2d0697885467c"),

    "movie" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b79b8387d467d5ab860544f")
    ],
    "takenSeats" : [{"id" : 1},{"id" : 2},{"id" : 4}, 
],

    "creteDate" : ISODate("2018-08-14T18:46:36.090Z"),

}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b79bb0c15d2d069788ef48d"),

    "movie" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b79b8387d467d5ab860544f")
    ],
    "takenSeats" : [{"id" : 2},{"id" : 7},{"id" : 4}, 
],

    "creteDate" : ISODate("2018-08-14T18:46:36.090Z"),

}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b79bb0c15d2d069788fg54hq"),

    "movie" : [ 
        ObjectId("5b79b8387d467d5ab8df54h43")
    ],
    "takenSeats" : [{"id" : 6},{"id" : 2},{"id" : 5}, 
],

    "creteDate" : ISODate("2018-08-14T18:46:36.090Z"),

}
```

As you can see, two of the documents contains the same id in the field `movie`.

What I trying to do is: to take those document that contains the same id in `movie` field and combine the `takenSeats` field

The wanted result should looks like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b79b8387d467d5ab860544f"),


    "takenSeats" : [{"id" : 2},{"id" : 7},{"id" : 4},{"id" : 1},{"id" : 2}, 
                          {"id" : 4}
],

    "creteDate" : ISODate("2018-08-14T18:46:36.090Z"),

}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b79b8387d467d5ab8df54h43"),


    "takenSeats" : [{"id" : 6},{"id" : 2},{"id" : 5}, 
],

    "creteDate" : ISODate("2018-08-14T18:46:36.090Z"),
}
```

In the last hours I tried to achieve it with different operators like `$push` and `$addToSet`. This is the query that I did that was the closest to the result that I want, but the issue that the documents that I was receiving in the result are with duplicated ids

```
db.orders.aggregate([
        {$match:{ "created":{$gt: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000*60*60*24*15)}}}, 
        { $lookup: { from: "shows", localField: "showId", foreignField: "_id", as: "acociatedShow" } },
        { "$project": { "acociatedShow": 1 } },
        { $unwind : "$acociatedShow" },
        { "$group": {"_id": { "movie": "$acociatedShow.movie"},
        "takenSeats": { "$addToSet": "$acociatedShow.takenSeats"}}},
        { $unwind : "$takenSeats" },  
        { $group : { _id : "$takenSeats", movieId : { $first: '$_id.movie' },len : { $sum : 1 } } },
        { $limit : 3 },
        { $lookup: { from: "movies", localField: "movieId", foreignField: "_id", as: "topMovie" } },
        { $unwind: "$topMovie" }, { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$topMovie" } }
 ])
```

[image: MongoDb]

Comment: Ignoring your query you would use `{"$unwind":"$movie"},
        {"$unwind":"$takenSeats"},  
        {"$group":{"_id": "$movie","takenSeats":{"$addToSet": "$takenSeats"},"creteDate":{"$first":"$creteDate"}}}` to get the expected response

Comment: @Veeram Thanks for you're help. You're direction is god, But as i understand add to set adding values to array unless they don't exist, Is there any solution to add values no meter if they exist or not?

Comment: yw. do you mean what happen when `movie` or `takenSeats` don't exist ? If yes you can $unwind with `preserveNullOrEmptyArrays` option.

Comment: @Veeram ,  I mean if the `takenSeats` fields that merged together contains the same ids (values) in both of the arrays , My wanted result that the both array should be combined **even if the values in there are the same** (like in the sample) , What I am getting now is that if there is values that already exist in both of the arrays so it ignoring them. I saw that something like this is maybe  available with the `$each` operator,
Thanks for you're help!

Comment: have you tried `$push` instead of `$addToSet` ?

Comment: Yes, tried with `$push` , The problem that it multiplies the results,

Comment: Have you tried unwinding the takenSeats before $group stage ?